# What is the pricing of a Pay As You Go iOS subscription introductory offer?

Tags: ios, storekit

I want to offer a pay-as-you-go introductory offer for a subscription in my iOS app. But it's not clear to me what the actual pricing is if the offer is on a subscription whose period is more than 1 unit (2 month, 3 month, 6 month, etc).

For example, say I have a subscription that costs $20 per renewal and renews every 6 months. I set up an intro offer of the "Pay as you go" type (`SKProductDiscountPaymentModePayAsYouGo`) whose duration is 12 months and price is $10. **Is the user going to get charged $10/month for 12 months (renewing 12 times), or $10 per 6 months for 12 months (renewing twice)?**

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_introductory_offers_in_your_app?language=objc) isn't all that clear on this. If I set this up with a [local StoreKit test file](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting_up_storekit_testing_in_xcode?language=objc) and try it in a simulator, the system purchase sheet appears to actually display it wrong - it's definitely not a 2 month trial (filed as FB8998598). Here's the StoreKit file:
[image: Xcode configuration]

And here's the simulator display when you purchase it:
[image: Simulator screenshot]

Comment: The purchase display definitely looks wrong.  The timeline in the documentation seems to explain what should happen - in your case they would pay $10 initially and $10 for the first renewal (after 6 months) and then pay $20 for each renewal

Comment: @Paulw11 that would make the most sense, but they don't actually label those time periods explicitly anywhere. I'm writing the logic to generate the string to describe the trial right now and want to make sure I get this right.

Answer (score 0):

The App Store Connect UI actually answers this question. In my scenario, it will charge $10 every 6 months for 12 months, which means 2 charges.

[image]